# Activity in a library project

Tags: java, android

I've an android library project, package name- com.example.lib, with an Activity called SecondActivity. I exported this library project as a Jar file, by including generated Source and Resources. I pasted this Jar file in the Host Application's "libs" folder. I also added this jar file into build path, by right clicking on it and selecting "Add to Build Path" option.

When I run this host application, I get NoClassDefFound Exception. Package name, activities names are different. I've also included the library project's Activity's details in the Host application's manifest. But I cant execute this successfully.

When I checked the "gen" folder of the Host application, I found out that library's R file is not getting generated. Below I've my manifest details.

please help me guys.

Mainfest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.secondapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.secondapp.SecActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.lib.firstapp.MainActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Error Log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.lib.firstapp.MainActivity
    at com.example.secondapp.SecActivity$1.onClick(SecActivity.java:23)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3571)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14247)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My intention is to Create a JAR file. My clients can use my application by implementing this JAR file into their application. I've tried implementing services and receivers in this JAR file. Only thing that I cant do is Activities. Can I include Activities in a JAR??

Comment: What are you trying to achieve , with this jar file

Comment: do not make jar file add this project as library project. Because jar can only hold java classes not xml,drawables etc resources.

Comment: i don't think it is possible to package resources as jar yet. You need to mark one as library project and reference the same in another project. You can check commonsware answer i guess i came across a close to your requirement with a workaround.

Comment: Hi, I need to create a JAR file, which can be implemented in other android applications by including this JAR file. Can we use Activities while creating JAR file?? I've done Services and Receivers.They are working fine. But Activities isnt.

Comment: I've edited my que, here I've explained my intention. Please help....

Comment: @Raghunandan: Thank u. I checked it out. I guess its the only way right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this [Create a JAR for Android Library Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622850/create-a-jar-for-android-library-distribution) will help. I unfortunately haven't had the time to try and through the answer to see if it works but it may help you

Comment: Excellent, least I know it should work for me now as well. Hopefully one day I'll get the chance to give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add the reference to Library project?

You can do that this way: Right click on project folder > Properties > on left menu select Android > Add... > Select library project. [UNCHECK "Is Labrary" checkbox]

Answer (score 0):

okay 
let's do this

Consider LibA --> lib Project activity
        and ProA --> it is Main Project Activity

STEP 1 -- define LibA in your main Project AndroidManifest.xml with package name , do not define in Lib Project

STEP 2 -- do not give same name to the resouces

STEP 3 -- start LibA with package name ex. com.full_packagename.LibA

in your condition please clean the project rebuild Lib Project as well as Main Project
i think there is problem with finding a class From jar file/ Lib Project

thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared your "SecondActivity" of library project into manifest of main project.All the library project activities must be declared in the manifest of main project

Comment: Also add this project by marking it as a library and not as a jar.Just right click library project go to Properties->Android->Is Library check it.